# Method return being assigned to variable

Tags: c++

I have a method that is returning a CString and placing it into a variable, however this variable is a parameter in the method.  Is there a better way to assign the return of the method into the variable?

Example:

```
CString foo = "foo";
foo = MakeBar(foo);
```

Comment: Pass a pointer inside your method and then you can just use that when the method finishes executing.  No assignment needed.

Comment: No, using the `=` operator is fine. What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I think it looks redundant having the same variable being assigned to a method that is using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass foo by reference into the function.  In that way it's understood that it will be an input/output parameter.

```
void MakeBar(CString &foo)
{
  if(foo == "foo")
    foo = "bar";
}

//...


CString foo = "foo"; 
MakeBar(foo);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine.  It's common (and often good practice) to write functions that don't modify their arguments.  In your case, you want to overwrite `foo`, so you have to assign the result to itself.

This idiom is *very* common in other languages that have immutable strings.

Comment: it is good functional style, much better than having side effects imho

Answer (score 0):

The question is how your `MakeBar()` function is typically *used*, how it is implemented. If there's a sizeable fraction of `foo2 = MakeBar(foo1)` calls, then it's better to have a return value. If you're sure that the output of `MakeBar()` always replaces the input, then the `void MakeBar(CString &foo)` form is better.